# Enviando Model para Controller via Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net, razor

Tenho uma View fortemente tipada com um pequeno formulário e uma função javascript com uso de ajax:

```
function emitir () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("EmissaoRapida", "CND")',
        data: { model: @Model },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.mensagem);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Erro na tentativa de emissão!");
        }
    });
}
```

Quero simplesmente enviar o meu modelo de dados para meu controlador, o método que receberá o model tem a seguinte assinatura:
    public JsonResult EmissaoRapida (EmissaoCND model)

Porém acontece algum erro, utilizando o depurador do Firefox eu percebi que tem algo errado no momento da passagem do modelo, pois o problema é que não é feita a leitura da raiz do projeto conforme quando faço a tipagem na view.
    @model Pro_Certidao.Areas.Usuarios.Models.EmissaoCND

No erro **Pro_Certidao** fica de uma cor diferente, acredito que o problema seja ali e a mensagem que temo é este: **Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: 'Pro_Certidao' não está definido**

Existe alguma forma de consertar isso ou fazer algo de forma semelhante enviando o modelo de dados completo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente passar no model o form serializado.

Supondo que seu form seja de id `formxpto`:

```
function emitir () {
    var model = $("#formxpto").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("EmissaoRapida", "CND")',
        data: model,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.mensagem);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Erro na tentativa de emissão!");
        }
    });
}
```

Ou por jQuery:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("EmissaoRapida", "CND")", $("#FormFinalizaOrdem").serialize()).done(function (retorno) {}
```

Sua controller deve receber o mesmo objeto do model, que no caso é `Pro_Certidao.Areas.Usuarios.Models.EmissaoCND`

Se der certo, poste para que ajude a outras pessoas.

**EDIT**

Sua model tem que estar com a anotação `[Serializable]`:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class EmissaoCND
{
      //Atributos...
}
```

Seu método da controller anotado com `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmissaoRapida(EmissaoCND EmissaoCND) {}
```

Comment: O erro já não acontece mais, pelo menos o navegador não reclama, porém quando chega no método do meu controller o model está null.

Comment: confira se seu método da controller está anotado com `[HttpPost]` e se sua model está com `[Serializable]`, do `System.SerializableAttribute`

Comment: Na controller estava tudo certo já, porém no Model eu adicionei o '[Serializable]' e nada ainda, mas não consigo colocar o 'using' correto, na verdade ele nem deixa eu adicionar o 'System.SerializableAttribute'

Comment: Editei o post  da resposta, dá uma conferida como seu model deve estar.

Comment: Tá basicamente igual, tanto a Model como a Controller. Única coisa diferente é que eu estou usando o EF e utilizo a DataAnnotation.Schema para relacionar melhor as coisas com o banco de dados

Comment: alterei o método `emitir()`, dá uma olhada..

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo abaixo;

```
function DeleteUser() {
    var dados = { Id: $("#deleteuser").val() };

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Usuarios/Delete",
            data: dados,
            success: function (msg) {                       

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
}
```